# Error Access to XMLHttpRequest at "http" from origin has been blocked by CORS policy - Graph API -

Tags: microsoft-graph, cors

I would like to retrieve list of recent files from a particular document library or site for the logged on user

This is using a content editor on a sharepoint classic site

When i run the code below i get error below

**Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://login.microsoftonline.com//oauth2/v2.0/token/' from origin 'https://tenant.sharepoint.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.**

Using the code below to get an access token and i get the error above

```
 var token;  
 $(document).ready(function () {  
     requestToken();  
 });  
    
 function requestToken() {  
     var clientId = ""
     var clientSecret = ""
     var tenantID = ""
     var uri = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/"+ tenantID + "/oauth2/v2.0/token"
    
     $.ajax({  
         "async": true,  
         "crossDomain": true,  
         "url": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantName/oauth2/v2.0/token", // Pass your tenant 
            
            
         "method": "POST",  
         "headers": {  
             "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"  
         },  
         "data": {  
             "grant_type": "client_credentials",  
             "client_id ": clientId, //Provide your app id      
             "client_secret": clientSecret, //Provide your secret      
             "scope ": "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default",
             "redirectUri" :  "https://tenantName.sharepoint.com"
         },  
         success: function (response) {  
             console.log(response);  
             token = response.access_token;  
             console.log(token);  
                
         },  
         error: function (error) {  
             console.log(JSON.stringify(error));  
         }  
     })  
 }
```

I have setup the app registrations and also added Redirect URIs for SPA and Web

Not sure what else I'm missing. Do i need any other settings in azure?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can anyone advice please? Can i get an access token if the script is in a sharepoint classic page?

Answer (score 1):

You can not fetch the details because of browser security feature. Use msal based authentication . Check for msal browser msal library.

Comment: Thats what i did and i finally got it working